# I have a problem with a "repeat" function in R

Tags: r

```
checknames <- function(){
  gamers <- c("Rebeca","Luis","Paco")
  games <- c("3","2","7")
  scores <- c(100,110,50)
  table <- data.frame(gamers,games,scores)
  r=0
  p=0
  repeat{
    print("Name Player 1: ")
    name1=scan(,what="character",1)
    for(i in 1:length(gamers)){
      if(name1==gamers[i]){
        r=readline(prompt = "This player is already in the file. Would you like to change the name? \n 1. Yes \n 2. No \n Select an option: ")
      }
    }
    if(r==2){
      break
    }
    if(r==0){
      gamers=c(gamers,name1)
      name1 <- data.frame(gamers=name1,games="1",scores="100")
      table <- rbind(table,name1)
      break
    }
  }
  table
  repeat{
    print("Name Player 2: ")
    name2=scan(,what="character",1)
    for(i in 1:length(gamers)){
      if(name2==gamers[i]){
        print("This player is already in the file. Would you like to change the name?")
        r=scan(,what="character",1)
      }
    }
    if(p=="No"){
      break
    }
    if(p==0){
      gamers=c(gamers,name2)
      name2 <- data.frame(gamers=name2,games="1",scores="100")
      table <- rbind(table,name2)
      break
    }
  }
  table
}
table <-checknames()
```

I was doing a code that ask the user 2 names, and it should prove if the table has this name, and if it not, add it, and if it has the name, ask the player if he/she wants to change it.

The problem is that when the player say that he want to change the name, the repeat function do not ever break, I think that is because of I assign something wrong (I assign r==2/r==0) and that is why the repeat function still repeating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues with your code. We will focus on the 2nd `repeat` loop you've written for player 2.

First of all, we can simplify the the `for(if(` loop you use to check if the name has already been taken. by checking the list all at once instead of looping through the entire index.

```
if(any(name2==gamers)){
        print("This player is already in the file. Would you like to change the name?")
        r=scan(,what="character",1)
      }
```

Now, moving on to some of your problems.you store the variable `r` in your scan but you are checking for the variable `p`. You should change the line in the above code block to read `p=scan(,what="character",1)`.

Furthermore, you now have a situation where if your user2 put in a name already taken, then changed it to something else, your code will never let them out as you do not have never set `p` back to `0`. This can be adressed by adding an `else { p=<-0 }` line.

All of the above changes are placed together here for you:

```
if(any(name2==gamers)){
        print("This player is already in the file. Would you like to change the name?")
        p=scan(,what="character",1)
      } else {
        p <- 0}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! I asked another question, could you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481454/how-can-i-iimit-the-data-that-the-user-write-in-r