# How can I Iimit the data that the user write in R?

Tags: r

```
checknames <- function(){
  gamers <- c("Rebeca","Luis","Paco")
  games <- c(3,2,7)
  scores <- c(100,110,50)
  table <- data.frame(gamers,games,scores)
  r=0
  p=0
  repeat{
    print("Name Player 1: ")
    name1=scan(,what="character",1)
    if(any(name1==gamers)){
      r=readline(prompt = "This player is already in the file. Would you like to change the name? \n 1. Yes \n 2. No \n Select an option: ")
    }
    else{
      r <- 0
    }
    if(r==2){
      break
    }
    if(r==0){
      gamers=c(gamers,name1)
      name1 <- data.frame(gamers=name1,games="1",scores="100")
      table <- rbind(table,name1)
      break
    }
  }
  table
  repeat{
    print("Name Player 2: ")
    name2=scan(,what="character",1)
    if(any(name2==gamers)){
      p=readline(prompt = "This player is already in the file. Would you like to change the name? \n 1. Yes \n 2. No \n Select an option: ")
    }
    else{
      p <- 0
    }
    if(p==2){
      break
    }
    if(p==0){
      gamers=c(gamers,name2)
      name2 <- data.frame(gamers=name2,games="1",scores="100")
      table <- rbind(table,name2)
      break
    }
  }
  table
}
table <-checknames()
```

Hi everyone, I did a code that ask the user to enter 2 names, and if this name is in the table, it should ask the user if he wants to change his name. The problem is, when the question of if he wants to change his name, I give him 2 option: "1" for Yes, and "2" for No, and I want that when the user enter other caracters like "t" or "7" (for example), the code said: "This option is unavailable, please chose another one" or something like that, and ask another time the question of if he want to change his name. Hope you can help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could restructure the `p` check `if` statements into an `ifelse` that check the cases you want in order if `p=2` then if `p=0` and lastly if `p not= 1`

```
 p=1
  repeat{

    if(p==1){
      print("Name Player 2: ")
      name2=scan(,what="character",1)

      if(any(name2==gamers)){
        p=readline(prompt = "This player is already in the file. Would you like to change the name? \n 1. Yes \n 2. No \n Select an option: ")
        if(p==0){p<-99}
      }else{
        p <- 0
      }

    }else if(p==2){
      break
    }else if(p==0){
      gamers=c(gamers,name2)
      name2 <- data.frame(gamers=name2,games="1",scores="100")
      table <- rbind(table,name2)
      break
    }else{
      repeat{
        p=readline(prompt = "This option is unavailable, please chose another one \n 1. Yes \n 2. No \n Select an option: ")
        if(p==1|p==2){break}
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: But it only works for the first time, when you write another time another character (neither 1 or 2), the code asks you another time the name for player 2...:(

Comment: good catch, I've edited my answer to address this by adding yet another repeat loop.

Comment: @JiakaiDong I edited it again, This time the entire name2 repeat loop is changed. It is also necessary to initialise `p=1` not 0. Now things work as intended.

Comment: Mate, the code the almost perfect. Because, when the program asks us if we want to change the name and we write 0 (so p=0), the program will break, and it is the same when the program tells us that the option is unavailable if we write "0", the program breaks :(

Comment: There's definitely a cleaner easier way to accomplish your overall task. But for the sake of a quick fix I edited in `if(p==0){p<-99}` at the right spot to catch that error.

Comment: Thank you, dude! I´m a beginner in R, that is why this is so complicated for me. I very appreciated your work Daniel, I wish you all the best!

Comment: I just realised you may want to include a catch for the case where the user hits enter without putting any text. something like `if(length(p)==0){p<-99}` and something similar for the names themselves.

Comment: Yes, you are right, because when the code asks for the name of the player, the code gives us an error. But I think it should be something like "if(length(name1)==0)", but I don´t know how to make the code repeat asking the name of player 1 when it occurs.